# Filtering Data out of 2 CSVs and Getting Objects within Object

Tags: powershell

So what I am attemping to do is filter some data through a csv from a csv and when it goes through it searches the column and give me all the values that have a matching value in the 2nd CSV from the 1st one. However the values its giving are the groups when in fact I need the devices that are in the groups. So kinda like a group of object inside of an object.

```
$Date = $(Get-Date -f MM_dd_yyyy)
$azuregroupdata = import-csv -Path "\\iPadIntuneMDM\CSV\$Date-AzureGroupsdata.csv"
 


$resultdata = import-csv -Path "\\iPadIntuneMDM\CSV\$Date-MatchinDevices.csv"
$groupsinboth = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($resultdata.NewGroup) -DifferenceObject ($azuregroupdata.DisplayName) -IncludeEqual | `
        Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "==" } | `
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject) 


$results2 = ForEach ($Group in $groupsinboth) {
    
    $A2 = $resultdata | Where-Object { $_.NewGroup -eq $Group }
    $I2 = $azuregroupdata | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $Group }
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        "Serial"          = $A2.Serial
        "ObjectID"        = $A2.ObjectID
        "AzureADGroupID" = $I2.ObjectId
    }
}
Write-Host $results2
$results2 | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path \\iPadIntuneMDM\CSV\$(Get-Date -f MM_dd_yyyy)-DevicesandgroupIDs.csv
```

In the CSVs I have the following data

AzureGroupsData

| #TYPE Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.Group |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DeletionTimestamp | ObjectId | Description | DisplayName | SecurityEnabled |
|  | 4e29b8b7-bdc7-4d21-a13b-5517514a791e | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | TRUE |
|  | 9737a1de-79f3-4e0c-8b47-0933bd5613e4 | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | TRUE |
|  | d7166f43-4562-4bff-8e92-e420df9b2e9c | iPad-PER-Students-ML03 | iPad-PER-Students-ML03 | TRUE |
|  | 1952810e-88da-49cd-bb8c-0edb26f61cd5 | iPad-SAE-Staff-ML01 | iPad-SAE-Staff-ML01 | TRUE |
|  | 39d2bc70-7ed8-4b9a-b4b4-b3843df7e20b | iPad-SAE-Students-ML04 | iPad-SAE-Students-ML04 | TRUE |
|  | 53b24a28-ee91-4c14-8020-21ab431c89de | iPad-RLE-Staff-ML01 | iPad-RLE-Staff-ML01 | TRUE |
|  | c40bb857-4388-4c26-9b68-b7ffa688a5d4 | iPad-GAE-Staff-ML04 | iPad-GAE-Staff-ML04 | TRUE |
|  | a4764233-3b7d-4420-838c-806d1db8ca05 | iPad-SAE-Students-ML02 | iPad-SAE-Students-ML02 | TRUE |
|  | 705d5fd0-b788-4158-b684-6f225783484a | iPad-EDC-Staff-IT | iPad-EDC-Staff-IT | TRUE |
|  | da75d1f7-7945-4cb1-9618-51f914651ea6 | iPad-SRC-Staff | iPad-SRC-Staff | TRUE |

ResultData

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ObjectID | Serial | NewGroup | DeviceID | OldGroup |
| 0fb06be4-13c3-4040-af68-85fae174895a | DLXNL73AG5YP | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 5f54d29a-aad6-4f41-98a0-ddf7a8c85250 | 4521 |
| 01c1628e-45d3-42d8-abd9-29f7f10ea321 | DMPNP6W0G5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | 14c4cbcd-4be7-498d-8fdd-be376a2b3a7a | 4597 |
| 0be2d71a-34cb-4f0a-a5dd-9b88d105c47a | DMPNP5SQG5VW | iPad-PER-Students-ML03 | 7e7b0c62-2f74-4000-aafb-1cc725d10ddd | 4633 |
| 1a4393bf-c89d-478c-aa86-ff23c3eedd66 | DMPNP65YG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 55d6ae86-e07a-4be5-ab0c-c3d8e9e5b4f4 | 4521 |
| 1d2afa19-ceb9-4e7c-8638-4e86607249d2 | DMPPX0RDG5YP | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 0995fd79-cdd3-4186-93ef-237356401aa4 | 4521 |
| 1d884772-645c-4044-bec7-24240af0a52a | DMPNP70WG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | da20b47a-658e-4a2e-a02d-9c49aa585739 | 4521 |
| 1ddee2c6-9326-47d1-a6a2-8b4fa410a1e4 | DMPNP6GNG5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | dab324ed-68c6-43e4-8b66-25dc204b0705 | 4597 |
| 31c4d5f8-14a6-468d-806c-e4848b98d08c | DMPNNW7SG5VW | iPad-SAE-Staff-ML01 | e1e15427-dd65-4174-a9c2-62bf63ed28cf | 4611 |
| 36e66c40-dfcd-41ff-b038-96d66fa07ffb | DMPNP685G5VW | iPad-PER-Students-ML03 | a1be4983-24e8-4063-ad4e-132c9efecffd | 4633 |
| 3e1d76b5-e633-4372-a9f7-13aa8c6364ad | DMPNP4U2G5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML04 | c6414402-ccb1-45ad-b756-fa8a987ff473 | 4600 |
| 3f5d7f96-a394-4c75-99c8-0a588437a6da | DMPNP51EG5VW | iPad-PER-Students-ML03 | 3c0d9145-a499-443e-a6a5-87deefe0d117 | 4633 |
| 4165c5f4-d57e-4cce-82ce-5b8a87ccecd5 | DMPNP5HQG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | d650e345-d978-482f-a418-543fede68299 | 4521 |
| 49ad55f2-dd4a-4598-80e8-c33d05afc3eb | DMPNP67RG5VW | iPad-PER-Students-ML03 | 4426c45f-bb12-4f70-9c8f-ab3db3aa2a7e | 4633 |
| 53bfa152-80f8-451f-9086-3c37d3d61d13 | DMPNP6Z3G5VW | iPad-RLE-Staff-ML01 | f75f767a-bac8-4a29-a57a-8362caeff759 | 4568 |
| 53d25bcc-f124-4ca9-afb1-cbf450a5116f | DMPNPPSVG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 2c100fbc-0d17-4209-9f8a-18253878a465 | 4521 |
| 57436992-5749-431e-8cca-a2476b8f656c | DMPPW3WFG5YP | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 212949c6-a49d-4d8a-89d1-fcc6939c7629 | 4521 |
| 599c5285-0b54-48cb-8d6a-8c79c3d3d7ca | DMPNP61JG5VW | iPad-GAE-Staff-ML04 | 491a581c-ef20-456e-8657-08cc63901603 | 4610 |
| 5a0bb215-059b-421e-9446-f6aed9cd62c4 | DMPNP6EUG5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | 3b23aa12-4f3b-44f7-944b-c3b69f74c9ff | 4597 |
| 6f096b30-6bc2-4289-a46e-7d91a08d5309 | DMPNPB9MG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 662a15bf-c2a9-48ce-922c-688377030c3f | 4521 |
| 74a84b5a-cdbb-4bd6-ae31-c0f785702ea2 | DMPNP6DRG5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML02 | b175a280-a3eb-4b25-ae2b-06b4b586e235 | 4598 |
| 766a1907-31cd-41f9-bfac-4a0fa3e2f514 | DMPPX0S2G5YP | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 25faf41f-5a52-4bfd-983e-5fe735530ee7 | 4521 |
| 7ab6b17b-08f3-45d7-afea-58ef01701d78 | DMPNP6D9G5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 7a6a2552-d683-4202-9b10-3d4af7bbbae5 | 4521 |
| 7c30ec0e-d754-4035-9762-b891f36bbc74 | DMPNP6ETG5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML02 | 3b254910-74ef-44c8-8d35-b63f7cad0cff | 4598 |
| 7ff51330-9687-48b3-bdca-82b539ac64bc | DMPN5PSYFK11 | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 009b60e4-d3ba-4df7-9bc9-71929963513e | 4521 |
| 8cdab7fe-bd1f-4a8b-8bb0-a4b4e15cf921 | DMPNP6WNG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 807635ac-5f55-4582-936a-7fb376e95003 | 4521 |
| 930d2407-074d-43c4-93c5-1724cd2e31d8 | DMPNP6JRG5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | 469bfe61-02f4-485e-93c3-bad2e63028ee | 4597 |
| 961b4b75-783f-4aa1-b012-7b4de13ab437 | DMPNP6FSG5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML02 | b5a96974-05ad-44be-9d9b-d66ee9b64252 | 4598 |
| 96300aec-5e6b-4ddb-90a3-d1aec58d4934 | DMPNP6VNG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 99114f99-b6de-4d0c-adda-125df8ee116b | 4521 |
| 9e4a9329-35d2-40c7-9e09-de0c9a809ced | DMPNP756G5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | c79bb992-7363-47b8-bcdf-b84e2312cf0c | 4521 |
| 9ee5d6a4-2ffc-46ae-9c65-4a50208d035d | DMPPX0PMG5YP | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 87f2149a-f853-4f4d-a1b4-89236b2c02b5 | 4521 |
| ac1daa36-6382-493c-914f-a55d934c3a06 | F9GDNNC8Q1GC | iPad-SRC-Staff | ebec06e9-2c12-49c1-806e-cc86d94053dd | 4677 |
| ad19d31e-11f2-450a-abee-1af1c9e4a7d4 | DMPNP65UG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 7a6e73ad-31cb-4ae5-9fb1-e63f64fad914 | 4521 |
| bd978541-6254-4ad1-bb4e-e7640dea083b | DMPNP6DBG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | 0f12fb3b-4cd8-4b2a-91d2-3bf824d4fdfb | 4521 |
| da8eb01e-2f5a-41d6-8ee3-a18c95a09256 | DMPNP6KSG5VW | iPad-EDC-PreDeploy | dc81d237-a6ad-497d-9109-08999a01209f | 4521 |
| e434527b-4371-48d6-8396-dc8d085c5a04 | DMPNP6D6G5VW | iPad-EDC-Staff-IT | 51a05fef-0161-41c6-a1ee-1955083ec8c6 | 4588 |
| e6d8ad88-6971-4169-ae49-c2616eedb523 | DMPNP6Q6G5VW | iPad-SAE-Students-ML01 | 368ac2e0-2e08-440d-9c10-812087bfe855 | 4597 |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Output $results2

| ObjectID | Serial | AzureADGroupID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31c4d5f8-14a6-468d-806c-e4848b98d08c | DMPNNW7SG5VW | 1952810e-88da-49cd-bb8c-0edb26f61cd5 |
| 3e1d76b5-e633-4372-a9f7-13aa8c6364ad | DMPNP4U2G5VW | 39d2bc70-7ed8-4b9a-b4b4-b3843df7e20b |
| System.Object[] | System.Object[] | 4e29b8b7-bdc7-4d21-a13b-5517514a791e |
| 53bfa152-80f8-451f-9086-3c37d3d61d13 | DMPNP6Z3G5VW | 53b24a28-ee91-4c14-8020-21ab431c89de |
| e434527b-4371-48d6-8396-dc8d085c5a04 | DMPNP6D6G5VW | 705d5fd0-b788-4158-b684-6f225783484a |
| System.Object[] | System.Object[] | 9737a1de-79f3-4e0c-8b47-0933bd5613e4 |
| System.Object[] | System.Object[] | a4764233-3b7d-4420-838c-806d1db8ca05 |
| 599c5285-0b54-48cb-8d6a-8c79c3d3d7ca | DMPNP61JG5VW | c40bb857-4388-4c26-9b68-b7ffa688a5d4 |
| System.Object[] | System.Object[] | d7166f43-4562-4bff-8e92-e420df9b2e9c |
| ac1daa36-6382-493c-914f-a55d934c3a06 | F9GDNNC8Q1GC | da75d1f7-7945-4cb1-9618-51f914651ea6 |
|  |  |  |

Comment: Please, share the CSVs as plain text instead of screenshots

Comment: Just a second let me get on that

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon There you go.

Comment: Hope my answer helps, I suggest to obfuscate the CSV data displayed on your question as it seems to be real data coming from Azure, at least the ObjectIDs.

Comment: So you want something like `$AzureHash=$AzureGroupsData|Group DisplayName -ashashtable;$resultdata | Where{$_.NewGroup -in $AzureGroupsData.DisplayName} | Select ObjectId,Serial,@{l='AzureADGroupID';e={$AzureHash[$_.NewGroup]}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object[]` in the result CSV means that there are multiple values found per *DisplayName* (i.e.: `iPad-PER-Students-ML03` has multiple appearances in the **big CSV**) hence why there are multiple *serials* and multiple *objectIDs*. This would require 2 nested loops to unroll all the data:

1. An outer loop to enumerate all rows of the **Azure Groups CSV**.
2. And, an inner loop to enumerate all rows of the **Big CSV** per appearance of **DisplayName / NewGroup**.

```
$azureGroups = Import-Csv 'this\is\theAZUREGROUPS.csv'
$bigCsvHash = Import-Csv 'this\is\theBIGcsv.csv' |
    Group-Object NewGroup -AsHashTable -AsString

$result = foreach($i in $azureGroups) {
    foreach($z in $bigCsvHash[$i.DisplayName]) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Serial         = $z.Serial
            ObjectID       = $z.ObjectId
            AzureADGroupID = $i.ObjectId
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv ....
```

Comment: I think you're over complicating things. Make your first hash, then just iterate through the big CSV, filtering for `$bigCSV|?{$_.NewGroup -in $hash1.keys}`, and that will only return results where the same group is present in both CSVs.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician you're right, I was over complicating it. I still prefer the nested `foreach` instead of `Where-Object` but yes, not even sure what I was thinking. Thanks